# CDH in a group of square matrices

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

This [paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1000/ICTERI-2013-p-352-359-ITER.pdf) says the CDH problem in a group of square matrices can be solved by a generalized Chinese remainder theorem. I wonder how this problem might be solved?

> DH protocol in the cyclic group of matrices
> $\langle M \rangle$, and the matrix $M$ is considered as public information. It is assumed that Alice
> generates a random index $x$, calculates the matrix $M^x$, and sends it to Bob. In turn,
> Bob generates a random index $y$, calculates the matrix $M^y$, and sends it to Alice.
> Then both subscribers raise the matrices obtained from a partner in their secret powers
> and calculate the sheared matrix (encryption key) $K=M^{xy}$. The matrix $M$ must be a high-order matrix (at least 100); ...
> However, in [3] it has been proved,
> that Yerosh-Skuratov protocol can easily be cracked based on **the generalized Chinese
> remainder theorem**."

Comment: In what set are the elements of the matrix considered? If it's the finite field $\mathbb F_p$, I think this [paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~dfreeman/papers/discretelogs.pdf) applies and shows a reduction of the DLP in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb F_p)$ to the DLP in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$. But that can't be called "generalized Chinese remainder theorem".

Comment: My specific problem is the security of Diffi-hellman in the group  $\text{GL}(n,2)$!

Comment: I think that the Freeman paper could be interpreted as "generalised CRT". The method is to lift into a field $GF(2^m)$ where all of the eigenvalues can be found. In this field, the matrices $M$ and $M^x$ diagonalise to eigenvalues. Then solving $n$ discrete logs with the eigenvalues of $M$ as the generators and the other diagonals as the targets gives $n$ congruences for $x$ modulo the order of the eigenvalue and these can be combined with CRT.